# How to iterate through an array send via AJAX in Java servlet?

Tags: javascript, java

I'm passing a json object in which value for the key is an array to a java servlet via AJAX.

```
{cruiseCodes: ["#1926","#7924","#1927"]}
```

And retrieving the value for cruiseCodes using `req.getParameterValues("cruiseCodes")`. How can I store these values into a java array or how can I iterate through the array values in java?

What I've currently done is created a json object and rewrote the data structure in java which outputs `{cruise: ["#1926","#7924","#1927"]}`

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("cruise", req.getParameterValues("cruiseCodes"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked eventhough the real concern was, is it really possible to copy an array just with the assignment operator. Any clarifications on that behalf is appreciated.

```
String [] array = req.getParameterValues("cruiseCodes");
```